# Combine two list of map java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have two lists of maps.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String,Object>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I want to combine these two list but limit the combined list to 10 elements but all the elements from list1 should be there(example if list1 size is 7 and list2 size is 8, my combined list should have 7 elements from list1 and 3 elements from list2).

Will the below code guarantee

```
List<String> newList = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).limit(10).
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I don't downvote this.. but you have several requirements on what kind of result you want. Why wouldn't you just write some little algorithm resulting in what you want?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri the combined list should have a limit of 10 and also should avoid duplicates

Comment: You say you want only distinct elements in the combined list. This is what a `set` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is for, but aside from that it's not fully clear to me what should be distinct. Should each map object in the list of maps be distinct?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and that's why I'm saying, that you have a quite specific, narrow and peculiar requirement.. what you would expect to be an answer? on line code? well, still, I would rather have gone to implement some own algorithm.. as - again, it's not a generic problem per se.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of the code is going to work fine.

This is a generic version of the same logic, which you can use for Lists of any type, that is `List<T>`.

```java
public static <T> List<T> contatLists(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    return Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
            .limit(10)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```